# gitlab launch shell pipelines with specific user

Tags: ssh, gitlab, gitlab-ci-runner

gitlab_version: 14.1.1-ee

I copied ssh-id to targuet host with the user "user".

When I create a pipeline with "shell" runner I have a problems to comunicate to other hosts by ssh.

I created a simple task with "id" command, this return "root".

How to launch gitlab pipelines with "user" user.

Thank's.

Comment: Could you provide some more detail? Do you have a `gitlab-ci.yml` file you can share? Have you run into errors with anything you've tried so far? Without more details we can't answer your question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found how to connect to linux target host with "other user" than "runner user".

**Procedure:**

1. Install `sshpass` on gitlab server host.
2. On `Project_name/settings/"CI/CD"/Variable`, create a pass_var with password
   string on key value.
3. On `pipeline/editor` in script line of .gitlab-ci.yml:

```
script:
- sshpass -p $pass_var ssh user@host_ip "hostname"
```